# Get address from the lat long using openlayer or ordinance survey api's

Tags: jquery, maps, openlayers-6

I'm using ordinance survey layer with open-layer 6 map. And tried to get the address of the particular location by its latitude and longitude. Search a lot in ordinance survey api's and on google but didn't find anything.Can anyone help me finding the address via its latitude and longitude.

Comment: Ordnance Survey have a Places API with reverse geocoding https://apidocs.os.uk/docs/os-places-overview but there are many free (subject to usage limits) alternatives available from mapping services such as Bing, Mapbox, Maptiler, Here, Nominatim, ESRI UK,etc.

Comment: Yes. You are right but in my code I'm using projection. and the coordinates which you will get via projection. Are shown invalid if you use openstreet and google map api. Here i'm using EPSG:2700 projection.
Thanks for your valuable time and answer.

Comment: You can use `ol.proj.transform` to change request coordinates and results between projections